# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException exception come if trying to read an excel sheet

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, appium

> > I am trying to read an excel sheet

**Added required Jars**

Added poi jars within .classpath are below

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="External_Jars/poi/commons-codec-1.10.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="External_Jars/poi/commons-logging-1.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="External_Jars/poi/curvesapi-1.03.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="External_Jars/poi/jsqlparser-0.8.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="External_Jars/poi/poi-3.14-20160307.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="External_Jars/poi/poi-excelant-3.14-20160307.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="External_Jars/poi/poi-ooxml-3.14-20160307.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="External_Jars/poi/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.14-20160307.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="External_Jars/poi/poi-scratchpad-3.14-20160307.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="External_Jars/poi/sqlsheet-6.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="External_Jars/poi/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar"/>
```

**Exception is -**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cell index must be >= 0
                at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow.getCell(XSSFRow.java:237)
                at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow.getCell(XSSFRow.java:224)
                at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow.getCell(XSSFRow.java:44)
                at com.hp.commercial.framework.common.JDBCExcel.updateTestCaseDoc(JDBCExcel.java:546)
                at com.hp.commercial.framework.common.WebDriverListener1.afterInvocation(WebDriverListener1.java:262)
                at org.testng.internal.invokers.InvokedMethodListenerInvoker$InvokeAfterInvocationWithoutContextStrategy.callMethod(InvokedMethodListenerInvoker.java:100)
                at org.testng.internal.invokers.InvokedMethodListenerInvoker.invokeListener(InvokedMethodListenerInvoker.java:62)
                at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runInvokedMethodListeners(Invoker.java:566)
                at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:713)
                at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
                at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
                at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
                at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

> > Read excel sheet code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
public class JDBCExcel{
    private Connection con = null;
    private ResultSet resultSet = null;
    private Statement st = null;
    private Workbook workBook = null;
    private FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    private String filePath = null;
    /**
     * WritingExcel method will be used with inline calling from method where
     * needed to update excel sheet after updating by POI.
     * @throws SQLException 
     */
    private void WritingExcel() throws SQLException {
        try {
            // closing connectiona and fileinput Stream for already oepened excel file          
            this.connectionClose();



    // creating fileoutput Stream and writing
        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath));
        workBook.write(fileOutput);

        // closing fileoutput Steram
        fileOutput.close();

        // Reloading excel file using fileinput Stream
        this.loadExcel(filePath);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
/**
 * load excel file from path. Based on its extension .xls or .xlsx, workbook
 * using POI As well, formal declaration to get connection for driver
 * manager using SqlSheet API
 * 
 * @param path
 *
 */
public void loadExcel(String path) {
    try {
        filePath = path;
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));

        // check extension of file to determine workbook type
        String fileExt = path.substring(path.indexOf(".")).toLowerCase();

        // create workbook class based on file extension
        if (fileExt.equals(".xls"))
            workBook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
        else if (fileExt.equals(".xlsx"))
            workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream)
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * getRowId method to get particular row idneified by id value in ID column
 * in Last-to-First manner. This will be handled by SqlSheet API
 * 
 * @param sheet
 * @param id
 * @return
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public Map<String, String> getRowbyID(String sheet, String id)
        throws SQLException {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    // TO DO.. how to execute Where in SQL Query in JAVA 8
    String strQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + this.getSheetFormat(sheet); // + " WHERE ID= '" + id +
    st = con.createStatement();
    resultSet = st.executeQuery(strQuery);

    ResultSetMetaData rmd = resultSet.getMetaData();

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        //drawback to read cell again..so this is used.
        String idCell = resultSet.getString("ID");

        // Temporary solution until Where clause working in SQL Query
        if (id.equalsIgnoreCase(idCell)) {

            int columntCount = rmd.getColumnCount();
            map.put(rmd.getColumnName(1), idCell);

            for (int i = 2; i <= columntCount; i++) {
                map.put(rmd.getColumnName(i), resultSet.getString(i));
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    resultSet.close();
    return map;
}
public String getValuebyParamName(String sheet, String paramName)
        throws SQLException {
    String strParamValue = "";  
    // TO DO.. how to execute Where in SQL Query in JAVA 8
    String strQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + this.getSheetFormat(sheet); // + " where ParamName = " + paramName;
    st = con.createStatement(); 
    resultSet = st.executeQuery(strQuery);
    while (resultSet.next()) {          
        // Temporary solution until Where clause working in SQL Query
        if (paramName.equalsIgnoreCase(resultSet.getString("ParamName"))) {
            strParamValue = resultSet.getString("ParamValue");
            strParamValue = (strParamValue == null) ? "" : strParamValue;
            break;
        }
    }
    resultSet.close();  
    return strParamValue;
}
public String getValueByAnyColumn(String sheet, String refColumn, String refKey, String targetCol)
        throws SQLException {
    String strValue = "";
    String strQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + this.getSheetFormat(sheet);
    st = con.createStatement(); 
    resultSet = st.executeQuery(strQuery);
    while (resultSet.next()) {          
        if (refKey.equalsIgnoreCase(resultSet.getString(refColumn))) {
            strValue = resultSet.getString(targetCol);
            strValue = (strValue.equalsIgnoreCase("$Null")) ? "" : strValue;
            break;
        }
    }       
    resultSet.close();      
    return strValue;
}
public String getNextValueOfColumn(String sheet, String column, String refKey) throws SQLException {
    String strValue = "";   
    String strQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + this.getSheetFormat(sheet);
    st = con.createStatement(); 
    resultSet = st.executeQuery(strQuery);
    resultSet.last();
    int resultSize = resultSet.getRow();
    resultSet.beforeFirst();

    while (resultSet.next()) {      
        if (refKey.equals(resultSet.getString(column))) {   
            if ((resultSize) == resultSet.getRow()) {
                resultSet.first();
                strValue = resultSet.getString(column);
                strValue = (strValue.equalsIgnoreCase("$Null")) ? "" : strValue;
            } else {
                resultSet.next();
                strValue = resultSet.getString(column);
                strValue = (strValue.equalsIgnoreCase("$Null")) ? "" : strValue;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    resultSet.close();
    return strValue;
}
public void updateParticularColumnValue(String sheetNm, String columnNm, String targetValue, String replaceValue, String... ParamName) throws Exception{
    // Declaring Variables
    String paramName = ParamName.length > 0 ? ParamName[0]: "";
    Iterator<Row> rows = null;
    ArrayList<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    // Opening spreadsheet
    Sheet sheetName = workBook.getSheet(sheetNm);

    // Collecting row Iterator
    rows = sheetName.rowIterator();
    // Reading first row of excel as column Titles
    if (rows.hasNext()) { columnNames = this.getAllColumnTitles(rows.next().cellIterator()); }

    boolean isForSingleRow = !paramName.isEmpty();
    // Reading rest of rows as column values
    while (rows.hasNext()) {
        // getting next row
        Row row = rows.next();

        if(isForSingleRow) {
            // not updating single row
            break;  
        }
        else {
            if (row.getCell(columnNames.indexOf(columnNm.toLowerCase())).getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase(targetValue)) {
                //Else update each row turn by turn in loop
                row.getCell(columnNames.indexOf(columnNm.toLowerCase())).setCellValue(replaceValue);
                if (rows.hasNext()) {
                    row = rows.next();
                    row.getCell(columnNames.indexOf(columnNm.toLowerCase())).setCellValue(targetValue);
                } else {
                    if (DriverScript.executionMode.equalsIgnoreCase("ITG")) { 
                        CommonUtils.getExcel(Excel.Files.User).updateParticularColumnValue(Excel.User.Password.name(), "ITGStatus", "Old", "New");
                    } else {
                        CommonUtils.getExcel(Excel.Files.User).updateParticularColumnValue(Excel.User.Password.name(), "Status", "Old", "New");
                    }   
                }
                break;
            }
        }                           
    }
    WritingExcel();     
}
public List<ExecutionConfig> getModules() throws SQLException {
    List<ExecutionConfig> listReturn = new ArrayList<ExecutionConfig>();
    String Product = DriverScript.product;
    String ProductExecutionconfig = Product + "ExecutionConfig";
    // TO DO.. how to execute Where in SQL Query in JAVA 8
    String strQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + this.getSheetFormat(ProductExecutionconfig); // +
                                                                // " WHERE SelectedToExecute='Yes' and Executed='No'";
    st = con.createStatement();
    resultSet = st.executeQuery(strQuery);
    Map<ExecutionConfig, Integer>unsortedExecutionConfigMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        // Temporary solution until Where clause working in SQL Query
        if ("Yes".equalsIgnoreCase(resultSet.getString("SelectedToExecute"))
                && "No".equalsIgnoreCase(resultSet.getString("Executed"))) {
            ExecutionConfig obj = new ExecutionConfig(
                    resultSet.getString("ModuleName"),
                    resultSet.getString("TestCategory"),
                    resultSet.getString("RiskLevel"),
                    0); //No priority as it is decided in next block

            unsortedExecutionConfigMap.put(obj, Integer.valueOf(resultSet.getString("ExecutionPriority").isEmpty() ? "0" : resultSet.getString("ExecutionPriority")));
        }
    }
    resultSet.close();
      Integer[] uniquePriorityNumbers = unsortedExecutionConfigMap.values().stream().sorted().distinct().toArray(Integer[]::new);         
      for(int currentPriority : uniquePriorityNumbers){                   
          unsortedExecutionConfigMap.entrySet().forEach(e -> 
            {
                if(e.getValue() == currentPriority){
                    ExecutionConfig eObj = e.getKey();
                    eObj.setModulePriority(listReturn.size());
                    listReturn.add(eObj);
                }
            });
      }  
    return listReturn;
}
public List<TestCases> getActionList(ExecutionConfig selectedConfig)
        throws SQLException {
    String strModule = selectedConfig.strModuleName;
    String strTestCategory = selectedConfig.strTestCat;
    String strRiskLevel = selectedConfig.strRiskLevel;
    List<TestCases> listReturn = new ArrayList<TestCases>();
    // TO DO.. how to execute Where in SQL Query in JAVA 8
    String strQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + this.getSheetFormat(strModule);
    st = con.createStatement();
    resultSet = st.executeQuery(strQuery);
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        String testCategory = resultSet.getString("TestCategory");
        String riskLevel = resultSet.getString("RiskLevel");
        if ("1".equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(resultSet.getInt("Enabled"))) && "Automated".equalsIgnoreCase(resultSet.getString("TestExecution")) && strTestCategory.equalsIgnoreCase(testCategory) && strRiskLevel.equalsIgnoreCase(riskLevel)) {
            TestCases obj = new TestCases(resultSet.getString("TCID"),
                    resultSet.getString("Action"),
                    testCategory,
                    riskLevel,
                    resultSet.getString("TestDescription"));
            listReturn.add(obj);
        }
    }
    resultSet.close();
    return listReturn;
}
public void updateExecutionConfig(String strModuleName,
        String strTestCategory) throws SQLException, IOException {
    // Declaring Variables
    String Product = getValuebyParamName(DriverScript.prodConfigSheetName,
            "Product");
    String ProductExecutionconfig = Product + "ExecutionConfig";
    Iterator<Row> rows = null;
    ArrayList<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    int updateRow = 0;
    // Opening spreadsheet
    Sheet sheetName = workBook.getSheet(ProductExecutionconfig);
    // Collecting row Iterator
    rows = sheetName.rowIterator();
    // Reading first row of excel as column Titles
    if (rows.hasNext()) {
        columnNames = this.getAllColumnTitles(rows.next().cellIterator());
    }
    // Reading rest of rows as column values
    while (rows.hasNext()) {
        // getting next row
        Row row = rows.next();
        // converting cell type to String type to read cell value as string
        row.getCell(columnNames.indexOf("modulename")).setCellType(
                Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        row.getCell(columnNames.indexOf("testcategory")).setCellType(
                Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        if ((String.valueOf(row.getCell(columnNames.indexOf("modulename")))
                .equalsIgnoreCase(strModuleName))
                && (String.valueOf(row.getCell(columnNames
                        .indexOf("testcategory")))
                        .equalsIgnoreCase(strTestCategory))) {
            {
                // updating row
                row.getCell(columnNames.indexOf("executed")).setCellValue(
                        "Yes");
                updateRow++;
            }
        }
    }
    LocalLogManager.logf.info(Product + "ExecutionConfig for Module "
            + strModuleName + " has been updated for rows " + updateRow);
    WritingExcel();
}
public void connectionClose() throws SQLException, IOException {
    if (con != null){
        con.close();
        fileInputStream.close();}
}
public Connection getCon() {
    return con;
}
public Statement getSt() {
    return st;
}
public void closeStmt() throws SQLException {
    if (st != null)
        st.close();
}
public void updateTestCaseDoc(String sModuleName, String sActionName,
        String sStatus) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    // Declaring Variables
    Iterator<Row> rows = null;
    ArrayList<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    String BrowserName = ((RemoteWebDriver)LocalDriverFactory.getDriver()).getCapabilities().getBrowserName();
    BrowserName = BrowserName.equalsIgnoreCase("Internet Explorer") ? "IE": BrowserName;

    System.out.println("BROWSER NAME IS XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX " + BrowserName);

    // Opening spreadsheet
    Sheet sheetName = workBook.getSheet(sModuleName);

    // Collecting row Iterator
    rows = sheetName.rowIterator();

    // Reading first row of excel as column Titles
    if (rows.hasNext()) {
        columnNames = this.getAllColumnTitles(rows.next().cellIterator());
    }

    // Reading rest of rows as column values
    while (rows.hasNext()) {
        // getting next row
        Row row = rows.next();
        // converting cell type to String type to read cell value as string
        row.getCell(columnNames.indexOf("action")).setCellType(
                Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);

        // checking if multiple cell has right value for paramiterziation to
        // update row
        if (String.valueOf(row.getCell(columnNames.indexOf("action")))
                .equalsIgnoreCase(sActionName)) {
            // updating row
            row.getCell(columnNames.indexOf(BrowserName.toLowerCase() + "_passfail")).setCellValue(sStatus);
        }
    }

    WritingExcel();
}

/**
 * getMappedColValues method to retrieve map object including MappedFields
 * type of object with first primary identifyable column name. This will be
 * handled by SqlSheet API
 * 
 * @param sheetname
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
public Map<String, MappedFields> getMappedColValues(String sheetname)
        throws Exception {

    String strQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + this.getSheetFormat(sheetname);
    Map<String, MappedFields> returnMap = new HashMap<String, MappedFields>();

    st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
            ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    resultSet = st.executeQuery(strQuery);

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        MappedFields mapFields = new MappedFields(resultSet.getString(2),
                resultSet.getString(3), resultSet.getString(4));
        returnMap.put(resultSet.getString(1), mapFields);
    }

    resultSet.close();
    return returnMap;
}

/**
 * getRowCount method to get total rows in sheet. This will be handled by
 * SqlSheet API
 * 
 * @param strSheetName
 * @return
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public int getRowCount(String strSheetName) throws SQLException {
    int totalRow = 0;

    String strQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + this.getSheetFormat(strSheetName);

    st = con.createStatement();
    resultSet = st.executeQuery(strQuery);

    while (resultSet.next())
        totalRow++;

    resultSet.close();
    return totalRow;
}

/**
 * getRowCount method to get total rows in sheet. This will be handled by
 * SqlSheet API
 * 
 * @param strSheetName
 * @return
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public int getActiveTCRowCount(String groupName) throws SQLException {
    String module, testCategory, riskLevel;
    module = groupName.split("_")[0];
    testCategory = groupName.split("_")[1];
    riskLevel = groupName.split("_")[2];

    String strQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + this.getSheetFormat(module);

    st = con.createStatement();
    resultSet = st.executeQuery(strQuery);

    int rowIndex= 0;

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        if (testCategory.equalsIgnoreCase(resultSet.getString("TestCategory")) &&
                riskLevel.equalsIgnoreCase(resultSet.getString("RiskLevel")) && 
                    "1".equalsIgnoreCase(resultSet.getString("Enabled"))){
            rowIndex++;     
        }               
    }

    return rowIndex;
}

/**
 * getAllRowValue method to get all rows of parameterized sheet.
 * 
 * @param strSheetName
 * @return
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public List<Map<String, String>> getAllRowValue(String strSheetName)
        throws SQLException {
    List<Map<String, String>> returnRowList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    String strQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + this.getSheetFormat(strSheetName);

    st = con.createStatement();
    resultSet = st.executeQuery(strQuery);
    ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = resultSet.getMetaData();

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        int columntCount = resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount();
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= columntCount; i++) {
            map.put(resultSetMetaData.getColumnName(i),
                    resultSet.getString(i));
        }
        returnRowList.add(map);
    }
    resultSet.close();
    return returnRowList;
}

/**
 * getPreDataSelectedModules method to get list of module. This will be
 * handled by SqlSheet API
 * 
 * @return
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public List<String> getPreDataSelectedModules() throws SQLException {
    List<String> listReturn = new ArrayList<String>();
    String product = DriverScript.product;
    String productExecutionconfig = product + "ExecutionConfig";

    // TO DO.. how to execute Where in SQL Query in JAVA 8
    String strQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + this.getSheetFormat(productExecutionconfig);
    /* + " WHERE CreateAutomationPreData='Yes' ORDER BY Ranking"; */

    st = con.createStatement();
    resultSet = st.executeQuery(strQuery);
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        // Temporary solution until Where clause working in SQL Query
        if ("Yes".equalsIgnoreCase(resultSet
                .getString("CreateAutomationPreData")))
            listReturn.add(resultSet.getString("ModuleName"));
    }
    resultSet.close();
    return listReturn;
}

/**
 * getAllRowValueForModules method to get list of module columns based on
 * provided strWhreCluase including module names. This will be handled by
 * SqlSheet API
 * 
 * @param strSheetName
 * @param strWhereClause
 * @return
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public List<Map<String, String>> getAllRowValueForModules(
        String strSheetName, String strWhereClause) throws SQLException {

    // Fetching module name values from strWhereClause parameter.
    List<String> moduleNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    Matcher p = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'").matcher(strWhereClause);
    while (p.find()) {
        moduleNames.add(p.group().replace("'", "").replace("%", "").toLowerCase());
    }

    List<Map<String, String>> returnRowList = new ArrayList<>();
    String strQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + this.getSheetFormat(strSheetName);
    /* + "WHERE " + strWhereClause; */

    st = con.createStatement();
    resultSet = st.executeQuery(strQuery);
    ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = resultSet.getMetaData();

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        if (moduleNames.contains(resultSet.getString(2).toLowerCase())) {
            int columntCount = resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount();
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            for (int i = 1; i < columntCount; i++) {
                map.put(resultSetMetaData.getColumnName(i),
                        resultSet.getString(i));
            }
            returnRowList.add(map);
        }
    }
    resultSet.close();
    return returnRowList;
}

/**
 * getAllColumnTitles method to provide all column names in
 * ArrayList<String> object This will be used by methods where only POI
 * worked.
 * 
 * @param cells
 * @return
 */
private ArrayList<String> getAllColumnTitles(Iterator<Cell> cells) {
    // Temporary variable to send
    ArrayList<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();
    // filling value of cells from parameter to arrayList<String>
    while (cells.hasNext()) {
        Cell cell = cells.next();
        columns.add(cell.getStringCellValue().toLowerCase());
    }
    // returning list of columns
    return columns;
}

private String getSheetFormat(String sheetName){
    if (System.getProperty("java.version").contains("1.8"))
        return sheetName;
    else
        return "[" + sheetName + "$]";
}

/** updateAnyColumnValue method to update any column value for single row or all rows
 * @param sheetNm -> Name of Sheet
 * @param columnNm -> Name of column to be updated with value
 * @param ParamValue -> Value to be updated to for given column name
 * @param ParamName -> Value of row identifier from frist column. If empty, assumed that all rows should be updated of given column with ParamValue
 * @throws Exception
 * @author Mitul Thesiya
 */
public void updateAnyColumnValue(String sheetNm, String columnNm, String ParamValue, String... ParamName) throws Exception{
    // Declaring Variables
    String paramName = ParamName.length > 0 ? ParamName[0]: "";
    Iterator<Row> rows = null;
    ArrayList<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Opening spreadsheet
    Sheet sheetName = workBook.getSheet(sheetNm);

    // Collecting row Iterator
    rows = sheetName.rowIterator();

    // Reading first row of excel as column Titles
    if (rows.hasNext()) { columnNames = this.getAllColumnTitles(rows.next().cellIterator()); }

    boolean isForSingleRow = !paramName.isEmpty();
    // Reading rest of rows as column values
    while (rows.hasNext()) {
        // getting next row
        Row row = rows.next();

        //if ParamName parameter is found with row identifier value from first column by default
        if(isForSingleRow) {
            // converting cell type to String type to read cell value as string
            row.getCell(0).setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);

            // checking if ParamName column title has same keyName of field as from parameter
            if (String.valueOf(row.getCell(0)).equalsIgnoreCase(paramName)) {
                // updating row
                row.getCell(columnNames.indexOf(columnNm.toLowerCase())).setCellValue(ParamValue);
                break;
            }
        }
        else //Else update each row turn by turn in loop
            row.getCell(columnNames.indexOf(columnNm.toLowerCase())).setCellValue(ParamValue);          
    }

    WritingExcel();     
}


public void updatedDataIncrementNumbers(String sheetNm, String ParamName, String ParamValue) throws Exception{
    // Declaring Variables
    Iterator<Row> rows = null;
    ArrayList<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Opening spreadsheet
    Sheet sheetName = workBook.getSheet(sheetNm);

    // Collecting row Iterator
    rows = sheetName.rowIterator();

    // Reading first row of excel as column Titles
    if (rows.hasNext()) { columnNames = this.getAllColumnTitles(rows.next().cellIterator()); }

    // Reading rest of rows as column values
    while (rows.hasNext()) {
        // getting next row
        Row row = rows.next();

        // converting cell type to String type to read cell value as string
        row.getCell(columnNames.indexOf("paramname")).setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);

        // checking if ParamName column title has same keyName of field as from parameter
        if (String.valueOf(row.getCell(columnNames.indexOf("paramname"))).equalsIgnoreCase(ParamName)) {
            // updating row
            //if(ParamValue.length() != 0) {row.getCell(columnNames.indexOf("paramname")+1).setCellValue(ParamValue);}
            row.getCell(columnNames.indexOf("paramname")+1).setCellValue(ParamValue);
            break;
        }
    }

    WritingExcel();     
}

public int getPriorityOfTC(String actionName, String groupName) throws Exception{

    String module, testCategory, riskLevel;
    module = groupName.split("_")[0];
    testCategory = groupName.split("_")[1];
    riskLevel = groupName.split("_")[2];
    int lastPriority = this.getMaxPriorityOfModule(module, testCategory, riskLevel);

    String strQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + this.getSheetFormat(module);

    st = con.createStatement();
    resultSet = st.executeQuery(strQuery);
    Map<String, Integer> foundTestMethods = new LinkedHashMap();

    try{
        while (resultSet.next()) {



            //if (resultSet.getString("Action").toLowerCase().equalsIgnoreCase(actionName.toLowerCase()) && 
            if (testCategory.equalsIgnoreCase(resultSet.getString("TestCategory")) &&
                        riskLevel.equalsIgnoreCase(resultSet.getString("RiskLevel")) && 
                            "1".equalsIgnoreCase(resultSet.getString("Enabled"))){

                foundTestMethods.put(resultSet.getString("Action"), resultSet.getString("ExecutionPriority").isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.valueOf(resultSet.getString("ExecutionPriority")));
            }
        }   

          Integer[] uniquePriorityNumbers = foundTestMethods.values().stream().sorted().distinct().toArray(Integer[]::new);

          int setPriroity = lastPriority;
          for(int currentNumber : uniquePriorityNumbers){                 

              if(currentNumber == foundTestMethods.get(actionName)){
                  for(Entry<String, Integer> keyValue : foundTestMethods.entrySet()){
                      if(keyValue.getValue() == currentNumber){
                          setPriroity++;
                          if(keyValue.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(actionName)){
                              break;
                          }
                      }
                  }
                break;
              }

              setPriroity += (int) foundTestMethods.values().stream().filter(e -> e.compareTo(currentNumber)== 0).count();
          }                   

          return setPriroity;
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        return lastPriority; //No matched row having same action name found
    }
}

public int getMaxPriorityOfModule(String moduleName, String testCategory, String riskLevel) throws Exception{

    int maxEligibleRowCount = 0;
    int loopCount = Integer.valueOf(DriverScript.listModule.stream().filter(e -> moduleName.equalsIgnoreCase(e.getStrModuleName()) &&
            testCategory.equalsIgnoreCase(e.getStrTestCat()) &&
            riskLevel.equalsIgnoreCase(e.getStrRiskLevel())).findAny().get().getModulePriority());

    for(int i=0; i<loopCount; i++){
        String strQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + this.getSheetFormat(DriverScript.listModule.get(i).getStrModuleName());

        st = con.createStatement();
        resultSet = st.executeQuery(strQuery);


        try{
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                if ("1".equalsIgnoreCase(resultSet.getString("Enabled"))){

                    maxEligibleRowCount++;
                }
            }       
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            return maxEligibleRowCount; //No matched row having same action name found
        }
    }

    return maxEligibleRowCount;
}
}
```

Comment: The error message seems to be clear. Can you add the code snipped that actually reads the sheet?

Comment: Your stacktrace states: `mercial.framework.common.JDBCExcel.updateTestCaseDoc(JDBCExcel.java:546)`: `JDBCExcel.java` code line `546` contains a `getCell(columnNumber)` where `columnNumber` is less than 0. So what line in your code is code line `546`? Then try to debug why [ArrayList.indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-) may return -1.

Answer (score 0):

The column names are not as expected. The `ArrayList columnNames` does not contain either

```
columnNames.indexOf("action")
```

or

```
columnNames.indexOf(BrowserName.toLowerCase() + "_passfail")
```

so that `indexOf` returns `-1`. Hence the `IllegalArgumentException` in `getCell`. Correct the column names in your Excel file and think about error handling for such cases.